# Flex container not adjusting to content

Tags: css, flexbox, width

I learned here:
[Multi columns list by css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613350/multi-columns-list-by-css)
how to make a self adjusting multi column list. However there is one problem left: The container doesn't adjust it's width to it's content:
https://jsfiddle.net/rkofktdz/3/

```css
ul {
    height: 40px;
    display:inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I can extend the container (ul) by applying a fixed width but I would like to have it self adjusting.
This is part of a three level menu being a bit more complex:
http://nachrichtentisch.de/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891709/when-flexbox-items-wrap-in-column-mode-container-does-not-grow-its-width

Comment: Thanks for that hint. No solution but a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this is what you wanted to achieve:

https://jsfiddle.net/rkofktdz/4/

```
ul {
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Have a look at my snippet: Arrangement in two columns is just what I need but additionally I need to adjust the container's (ul's) width to it's content so that it encloses **both** columns.