# CSS correct li order for multiple column layout

Tags: css, layout, position, html-lists, multiple-columns

I have the following code and am trying to find out the best way to make the 4 columns necessary .

```
<ul>
  <li class="first-column">row1 column1</li>
  <li class="first-column">row2 column1</li>
  <li class="first-column">row3 column1</li>
  <li class="second-column">row1 column2</li>
  <li class="second-column">row2 column2</li>
  <li class="third-column">row1 column3</li>
  <li class="forth-column">row1 column4</li>
</ul>
```

Usually I would go about this with the css below, but this doesn't maintain li in the correct order (the first 3 li's are in the first column).

```
 .first-column, .second-column, .third-column, .forth-column {
   width:25%;
   float: left; 
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? What went wrong, or didn’t work?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your time, Ive just edited the question with what ive tried.

Comment: You can find similar answer here as this may look like its duplicate forum:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613350/how-can-i-create-multi-columns-from-a-single-unordered-list

Comment: Unfortutely the solution on that post is similar to the css posted in the question in that it doesn't put the li in the correct order required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a CSS grid job:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.first-column {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.second-column {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.third-column {
  grid-column: 3;
}

.forth-column {
  grid-column: 4;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="first-column">row1 column1</li>
  <li class="first-column">row2 column1</li>
  <li class="first-column">row3 column1</li>
  <li class="second-column">row1 column2</li>
  <li class="second-column">row2 column2</li>
  <li class="third-column">row1 column3</li>
  <li class="forth-column">row1 column4</li>
</ul>
```