# Responsive multi column list

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Say I have a list, which, on mobile, is arranged like this:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

On desktop, I want them to arrange like this:

```
A   D
B   E
C   F
```

I tried using a `flexbox` but I get this:

```
A   B
C   D
E   F
```

What is the best way to achieve this responsive reflow?

Comment: Do you have some code to reproduce it ?

Comment: Possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42613421/5641669 (plus an according media query with a different `column-count` setting)

Comment: Show us some code, what you have tried. At the minimum your mark up. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```css
.container {
      column-count: 2;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
      .container {
        column-count: 1;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
      <div>D</div>
      <div>E</div>
      <div>F</div>
</div>
```