# Order of CSS grid items with 2 grid columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a Grid layout with 11 grid items. I have used grid-auto-flow: row; so that the items are divided into 2 columns distributing an appropriate equal height for each column based on the number of items. However, The grid items are not displayed in proper order and instead they are displayed side by side. For example when there are 11 grid items, I want the 1st column to display grid items 1,2,3,4,5 & 6 and 2nd column to display grid items 7,8,9,10 & 11. How can I achieve this using CSS/JS without rearranging the grid items or placing 2 divs inside the container div?

The output that I want:

[image]

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: start;
    margin: 0 16px;
    row-gap: 32px;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
}

.grid-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.number {
    align-self: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 0.75rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
    border-radius: 0.125rem;
    background-color: #f2f3f5;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #111827;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    min-width: 54px;
    max-width: 54px;

}

.item-content {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    line-height: 1.25rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.75rem;
    color: #CBD5E0;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: -0.25rem;
    margin-bottom: -0.25rem;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Grid Items</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
              2
            </div>
            <div class="item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                3
            </div>
            <div class="item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
              4
            </div>
            <div class="item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                5
            </div>
            <div class="item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
               6
            </div>
            <div class="item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                7
            </div>
            <div class="item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
              8
            </div>
            <div class="item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                9
            </div>
            <div class="item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                10
            </div>
            <div class="item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                11
            </div>
            <div class="item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: To see a specific example of css multicolumn layout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42614178/2756409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `grid` rules if you have a hard coded amount of row/cols

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
grid-auto-flow: column;
```

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: start;
    margin: 0 16px;
    row-gap: 32px;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    
}

.grid-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.number {
    align-self: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 0.75rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
    border-radius: 0.125rem;
    background-color: #f2f3f5;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #111827;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    min-width: 54px;
    max-width: 54px;

}

.item-content {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    line-height: 1.25rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.75rem;
    color: #CBD5E0;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: -0.25rem;
    margin-bottom: -0.25rem;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Grid Items</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                1
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                2
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                3
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                4
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                5
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                6
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                7
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                8
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                9
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                10
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                11
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

If you would like a dynamic amount of rows, you'll need to add a class to each odd element to set `grid-column-start`.

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
    
}

.grid-item {
    grid-column-start: 2;
}

.grid-item-left {
    grid-column-start: 1;
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: start;
    margin: 0 16px;
    row-gap: 32px;
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
    
}

.grid-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-column-start: 2;
}

.grid-item-left {
    grid-column-start: 1;
}

.number {
    align-self: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 0.75rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
    border-radius: 0.125rem;
    background-color: #f2f3f5;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #111827;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    min-width: 54px;
    max-width: 54px;

}

.item-content {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    line-height: 1.25rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.75rem;
    color: #CBD5E0;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: -0.25rem;
    margin-bottom: -0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Grid Items</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="grid-item grid-item-left">
            <div class="number">
                1
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item-left">
            <div class="number">
                2
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item-left">
            <div class="number">
                3
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item-left">
            <div class="number">
                4
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" grid-item grid-item-left">
            <div class="number">
                5
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" grid-item grid-item-left">
            <div class="number">
                6
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                7
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                8
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                9
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                10
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" grid-item">
            <div class="number">
                11
            </div>
            <div class=".item-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus quasi eos sint illum autem, ipsum quis. Minima autem hic fugit.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This can be made 'more dynamic' by using some JavaScript to assign the classes

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Is there anyway to do this without specifying the number of rows as 6, because the number of grid items can change. So for example if the user decides there are 20 items and assuming all items are of equal size/height i want the 1st column to display 10 items. Hence the reason why i used grid-auto-flow: row.

Comment: Nope, well, if you want to do this dynamic, you'll need a class on each odd rows.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired layout with 11 grid items divided into two columns, you can use a combination of CSS and JavaScript. Here's an example of how you can achieve this without rearranging the grid items or adding additional divs:

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item">11</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(0, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

JS:

```js
const gridItems = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
gridItems.forEach((item, index) => {
  const column = index < 6 ? 1 : 2;
  item.style.gridRowStart = `auto`;
  item.style.gridColumnStart = `${column}`;
});
```